# Transfer all cells, formatting, formulas into new workbook for all sheets

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

My Excel workbook is getting incredibly slow to save, even though I have manual calculation on, nothing crazy going on in the vlookups, etc. But it spends so much time recalculating and I am wasting hours on this.

Is there any clean, easy way to just copy/paste all the contents of all the sheets (cell values, equations, etc) into a new workbook just in case the old one happens to be corrupted?

Comment: you may be better off [cleaning your current workbook up](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20clean%20an%20slow%20performing%20excel%20workbook). Sometimes there's even rougue formatting in cells that you can get see. Doing a `.UsedRange.LastRow` method in the immediate window of the VBE can show you if this is the case. Delete any rows that are unused. If the LastRow shows up in the last piece of actual data you are good. (LastRow may not be exact method, but you get the point, hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Check each sheet by hitting control+End. Does any take you to a row and or column far outside of your actually used range? If so, delete entire rows and columns past your REALLY used last cell (repeat for each worksheet) and then save a copy of your file.

Also, the xlsb file format is smaller so quicker to save and open.

Finally, if your wb is slow to calculate there is room for improvement. Any SUMIF(s) or array formulas in there? You say nothing crazy on the vlookup. What do you mean by nothing crazy? How many are there and to how many cells do they refer?